# Cannot play video on PhoneGap using HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-video

I am attempting to play local mp4 format video using jQuery Mobile on PhoneGap. On Android the video plays, but doesn't show anything except a white screen. I tried several different things, but none of them are working.

When I click the fullscreen button it plays in the native player. I want to show the video before clicking the fullscreen button.

My `video` tag:

```
<video id="html5_video" poster="" width="480" height="360" src="" autoplay>
    <i>OOPS, Your Browser doesn't support the HTML5 &lt;video&gt; element.</i>
</video>
```

Comment: What format is the Video you trying to play?.

Comment: mp4 video format only

Comment: hi any ideas means let me know please

Comment: Ok a few things to check ---  (1) do you have --- <!DOCTYPE html>  -- at the top of your HTML page? (2) The video might say MP4 but thats just a contaniner. HTML video supports --- MP4 = MPEG 4 files with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec. --- check the properties of the video. Also check this --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats --- on how to use the (video) tag properly and here --- http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_video.asp

Comment: go through this one https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video/tree/master

Comment: ya i tried but its working local videos only

Comment: you need live videos ah?

Comment: yes local and live video

Comment: check this https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer

Comment: ya now i am using this only. no other way ah ?

Comment: I've seen this issue on several sites. I've not looked into it in any detail but I seem to recall its to do with the video playing but not being rendered inside the actual container on the page. As something of a stab in the dark I'd suggest having a play with z-indexes.

Answer (score -4):

**html code:**

```
<iframe id="playvideo" style="width:95%;height:95%"></iframe>
```

**javascript:**

```
var videoPath="http://www.yourvideo path here"

document.getElementById('playvideo').src = videoPath;
```

Comment: i need to load .mp4.. t tried but video not loading into iframe